# Django fixtures: UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: django, unicode, yaml, fixtures

I have a Django model, goes like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

(User is django.contrib,auth user)

I'm trying to load data into my Postgres database in a yaml fixture, here's code:

```
-   model: auth.User
    pk: 1
    fields:
        username: admin
        password: 'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$7H9GitTtDND4$XWUCV1jgEU0QZbbitGXJrp5tcEEPRYS6WYVfdm3AcXo='

-   model: rbac.Employee
    pk: 1
    fields:
        user: 1
        name: admin
```

The problem is, that when i run `./manage.py loaddata fixture.yaml` I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/tomus/dev/bsk/venv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/tomus/dev/bsk/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/tomus/dev/bsk/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 229, in run_from_argv
        stderr.write('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 94-95: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried changing encoding of the fixtures file to ascii, no effect.

Comment: But I don't see any non ascii char in the fixture? How's so?

Comment: Did you succeed changing the encoding of the fixture to ascii?

Comment: Yes, here's the output of file -i fixture.yaml: `fixture.yaml: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Comment: And the whole file is what you show us?

Comment: Hint, use `xxd` or any HexEditor to see if any of the bytes in the file is over 128.